# Need simple PowerShell watcher script

Tags: powershell

I have a folder used as a holding area for PDF files that were not properly processed. I’ve been asked to design a script that watch for new files and log time when file appear in this "fail" folder in a log.txt. But now I need to create a function that runs every 12 minutes and checks the folder for any new files. If it finds files, it moves them into another directory C:\Users\jassu\Desktop\test\in to be processed, and then starts watching again.

Please suggest something simple
Thank you

Here's my PowerShell script:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
PS C:\Windows\system32> $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
PS C:\Windows\system32> $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\jassu\Desktop\test\fail"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
PS C:\Windows\system32> $action = { 
               $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
>>                 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
>>                 $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
>>                 Add-content "C:\Users\jassu\Desktop\test\fail\log.txt" -value $logline
>>               }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen nothing, it's working I just need to expand with move function that moves all files in fail folder to in folder every 12 minutes. Everything I've tried not working, so if you can suggest something I'll be very thankful

Comment: Put `Move-Item "C:\Users\jassu\Desktop\test\fail\*" -Destination C:\target\folder` in another script and execute it every 12 minutes with task scheduler?

Comment: You might need to wait for the files to be unlocked before being able to move them?